# Grafana LDAP integration with Orgs or Teams

Tags: ldap, grafana

I am wondering if its possible to configure LDAP groups with Orgs. or teams in Grafana so that as new users in those ldap groups login, they are attached to the right teams or orgs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/ldap/), it can be done in the **[[servers.group_mappings]]** section, in the configuration file (/etc/grafana/ldap.toml). LDAP must be enabled in the main configuration file (/etc/grafana/grafana.ini)

/etc/grafana/grafana.ini:

```
[auth.ldap]
enabled = true
```

And /etc/grafana/ldap.toml:

```
# Map ldap groups to grafana org roles
[[servers.group_mappings]]
group_dn = "LDAP group"
org_role = "Grafana role"
org_id = 1 #The number for the org I want these people to go to, for example, 1
```

Main Org is 1 and you can see the number for other orgs under Grafanas' Menu > Admin > Global Orgs.

Comment: Yes I see that, I have ldap enabled and I have set my group to be admin and others as viewers, but all people from all groups login in under the main org. What we are hoping to do is automatically set all users into their own orgs or atleast teams and have permission set by that.

Comment: I don't know if I'm following, but if you want to map LDAP groups to Grafana Organizations, yes, it's possible. In the same documentation you have an example, you just have to set the org_id variable for each group. I'll update the answer...